# How do I add an IF statement to this javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I have a basic slider that displays how much money a user saves based on how many sales they're currently making from their music. I want to add an IF statement that says "If the slider value is below 300 annual sales, echo £0 saving".

The code I am currently using has a linear calculation of a £5 saving per 100 sales (data.value / 20). Here's the code:

```
<form action="#">
    <input id="one" type="text" data-slider="true" value="100" data-slider-highlight="true" data-slider-step="50" data-slider-snap="true">
    <span class="output"></span>
</form>

<script>
    $("[data-slider]")
        .each(function () {
            var input = $(this);
        })
        .bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {
            $(this).nextAll(".output:first").html(data.value.toFixed(0));
        });
    $("#one").bind("slider:changed", function (event, data) {
        $(".distributor span").text("£" + data.value / 20)
    });
</script>
```

Any ideas on how I could add in an IF statement?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I have the correct part of your code:

```
$("#one").bind("slider:changed", function (event, data) {
    var
        dataValue = data.value,  /* Store data.value in a variable */
        value = dataValue < 300  /* Check if our variable's value is below 300 */
                ? 0              /* If it is, set value to 0 */
                : dataValue / 20 /* Otherwise set value to dataValue / 20 */
    ;

    $(".distributor span").text("£" + value)
});
```

This uses a [conditional (or ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) which determines what the value of our end "value" variable should be.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `data.value < 300 ? 0 : data.value / 20` instead?

Comment: @h2ooooooo It could be, but @James Donnelly has assigned the value to the `dataValue` variable first thats all.

Comment: @h2ooooooo exactly what @philreed said above. I've assigned this to a separate variable so as not to 1. unnecessarily pull the `value` property from the `data` object multiple times, and 2. unnecessarily perform the division multiple times.

Comment: @philreed Except `data.value < 300 ? 0 : data.value / 20` =/= `data.value / 20 < 300 ? 0 : data.value / 20`? OP mentions that if the slider is less than 300 then output 0. Not if the slider divided by 20 is less than 300 (and hence the slider must be more than 6000)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#one").bind("slider:changed", function (event, data) {
  if(data.value>300){
    $(".distributor span").text("£" + data.value / 20)}
  else{$(".distributor span").text("£ 0")
  }
});
```